# Is System.object is primitive itself?

Tags: c#

I have seen many people talking about inheritance in C# like primitive types are derive from System.Object and they some time pass integer, string... to object as arguments to methods. I have a few questions in my mind which confused me.

1) Is System.Object itself a primitive type?

According to my understanding derived classes are sophisticated versions of a base class[image: class inheritence diagram]

2) How does System.Object catch the arguments(string,int..) in the methods like

```
public void objcttest(object objct)
{
   if(objct is string)
       var strng = (string)objct;
}
```

3) What does this mean, using the classes defined in the above image?

```
Object objct = new WorkItem(); // how is the object of the base class type instantiated with derived class type
```

Comment: This is worded quite confusingly...

Comment: Too broad question. You should split them into 3 questions (and 2 and 3 are answered here already on SO). To answer first, object is not primitive (few basic types like int, bool etc are - type.IsPrimitive() gives you that).

Comment: Find a tutorial about C# and Reference Types.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i surf many but not succeeded to find my answer.what you can recommend please do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) system.object is itself primitive type?

No. From `Type.IsPrimitive`:

> The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single.
>
> How System.object catch the arguments(string,int..) in the methods like

There's a conversion from every non-pointer type to `object`.

> how the object of the type base class is instantiated with Derive Class

It isn't. You need to distinguish between three things:

- A *variable* (`objct` in your example)
- A *reference* (just a way of getting to an object)
- The object itself

The value of `objct` is just a reference. The idea is that you can convert an expression of type "derived type" to its base type (or interface it implements) without actually changing the reference itself.

This is basically the root of polymorphism in .NET - and too big a topic to do *true* justice to here; I would strongly suggest that you read a good introductory book on C# to get a good grounding on this.

Comment: I dunno how you get really good answers - even though the question sucks.

Comment: @skeet thanks but then how we say that int,string are the derivatives of System.object as these are primitive.

Comment: @Irfan: Well `string` isn't a primitive to start with (see the list). But they are value types. It's more that they can be *converted* to `System.Object` via boxing, and they inherit members that way too. But you should really look at how value types and reference types are stored. I recommend reading CLR via C#.

Comment: @skeet many many thanks but please if you can recommend a right place for CLR via C# other than Msdn do it please.

Comment: @Irfan: Yes, Amazon. (It's a book.)